# What is this succulent with cylindrical leaves?

Tags: identification, indoors

I saw this plant today in the shop. It wasn’t labeled. What is it?[image: plant]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a Barberton Groundsel, [Senecio barbertonicus](https://worldofsucculents.com/senecio-barbertonicus-succulent-bush-senecio-barberton-groundsel/).

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit more about this plant?  Light, water, location?

Comment: Only thing I can add that the link (ty for linking) doesn't is that ime, they don't bounce back from prolonged dry-out, nor propagate, as quickly as most succulents. My sample size for this genus is small, but they've demonstrated their thirst. Loves nitrogen and hates chlorine/chloramine.

Comment: @PaulNardini would you move the comment into your answer.  tks